# Spring Bean Scopes Step Scope and Singleton

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-framework-beans

Can someone explain what would happen if I declared a bean of step scope (used during batch processing) and the same bean of scope singleton to be used for another purpose (api calling).

```
   <bean id="sdlExcelFileProcessor" class="ms.rs.batch.SDLExcelFileProcessor" scope="step">
   <bean id="sdlExcelFileProcessor1" class="ms.rs.batch.SDLExcelFileProcessor" scope="singleton">
```

Comment: As they are named the same there will only be one bean. This would error out probably due to non-unique ids else it would error out on injection without specifying the explicit name.

Comment: posted same name by mistake. corrected the question. @M.Deinum

Comment: And your question is? You get 2 beans, 1 scoped, the other not scoped. When injecting and the name doesn't exactly match the name of the bean (or there is no `@Qualifier`) yu will get an error with autowiring (as there are 2). But basically you will have 2 beans one scoped, the other not scoped.